# unable to fix udev installation,

Tags: nvidia, dpkg, udev, groups

ubuntu 20 (focal).
if i try to run
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

i get following error

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 xserver-xorg-core
 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460
 nvidia-driver-460
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

To fix this, i tried re-installing udev (after cleaning /var/cache/apt/archives/udev*.*

by command
sudo apt update && sudo apt install udev
this errors out

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
udev is already the newest version (245.4-4ubuntu3.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up udev (245.4-4ubuntu3.6) ...
The group `render' already exists and is not a system group. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
```

I see, at some point in past, i had tried installed afanasy (cgru) network rendering system. This also created a user & group 'render'
this might be conflicting with what udev required.

Q. what is best way to solve this.? **The group `render' already exists and is not a system group. Exiting.**

Any ideas will be of huge help. thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: It looks like you have correctly identified the problem - it's hard to see a way around it short of modifying the group name used by the cgru software

Comment: yes my bad, its ubuntu 20.04 (LTS).
@steeldriver, i am willing to remove cgru software.
Q. should i delete user & group 'render' , restart machine and try re-installing.?

Main Question is, what exactly is systemgroup.? how can i tweak render user or group permissions so udev think it is part of system group.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved above problem by steps below

1- remove cgru (afanasy). nothing was copied specially, except two files.

- sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/afrender.service
- sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/afserver.service

2- remove render user and group

- sudo deluser --group render

3- re-install udev

- sudo apt-get install -f udev

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.
But my offensive group was:

```
The group `kvm' already exists and is not a system group. Exiting.
```

And I realized, by using Ctrl+R, that I had manually add them when I installed Boxes.

```
adduser $USER kvm
sudo addgroup kvm
```

So first I uninstalled Boxes, with `flatpak uninstall Boxes` and then I had to remove some manually installed dependencies on my Ubuntu machine:

```
sudo apt purge qemu-kvm
sudo apt purge libvirt-qemu
```

And finally, I could delete the kvm users and group:

```
sudo deluser libvirt-qemu
sudo deluser --group kvm
```

And then

```
sudo apt install udev
```

fixed the problem.